# linux buffer overflow - Art of Exploitation To Old?

Tags: c, linux, overflow, stack-overflow

I'm reading the book "Art of Exploitation".

Which is a good book but every exploit i've come across so far hasn't worked for me. In my opinion i've followed to the letter, granted no one is perfect so i might still have made an mistake.

But i came across some comments that said that the linux OS has been updated allot since the book was written.

So i wanted to ask if anyone knew if the examples in the books is outdated or if anyone i am supposed to follow to the letter or if i have to design some bits of the code for it to work?

NOTE:
I've read to around page 60.

I've tried overflowing the program with both writing the exploit.c code aswell as with manually with perl.

This is the code i've been trying to overflow:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buffer[500];
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The guys writing operating systems have also read the book and are adding defenses against the hacks. Like not allowing you to execute code on the stack.

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Stack_Smashing_Protector

Comment: You might enjoy [IO](http://io.netgarage.org/) it involves using exploits like this and the files are compiled in a way that attacks like this are possible.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for answers and read tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I haven't read the book, but from what I can say in general.

Zero-day exploits (functional on most recent updated version of software) do not last long and are generally made unusable before any such book comes out by the software authors (the book's author usually reports them). Operating systems/compilers add new and new protections, but these protections mostly take effect only on newly compiled code (which means old one is still vulnerable even on new system) and the protections are possible to evade anyway (just much more difficult).

As for your example. It depends what you are trying to do with the exploit. But as long as only basic learning is concerned, try turning off DEP, ASLR and already mentioned SSP when compiling, that should make it work easily.
If you are using gcc, then:
`-fno-stack-protector`, `-z execstack`
also `-O0` and `-g` might help in finding out other problems.